# react native webview not display html content

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display the following content in my webview, the screen is blank, any ideas?

```
<WebView source={{ html: content }} />
```

html:

```
<p>This is an example page. It&#8217;s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say something like this:</p>



<blockquote class="wp-block-quote"><p>Hi there! I&#8217;m a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night, and this is my website. I live in Los Angeles, have a great dog named Jack, and I like piña coladas. (And gettin&#8217; caught in the rain.)</p></blockquote>



<p>&#8230;or something like this:</p>



<blockquote class="wp-block-quote"><p>The XYZ Doohickey Company was founded in 1971, and has been providing quality doohickeys to the public ever since. Located in Gotham City, XYZ employs over 2,000 people and does all kinds of awesome things for the Gotham community.</p></blockquote>



<p>As a new WordPress user, you should go to <a href="http://app.rguc.co.uk/wp-admin/">your dashboard</a> to delete this page and create new pages for your content. Have fun!</p>
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#source as you're using directly put HTML, you should have the props originWhitelist set to ["*"].

Comment: Did you try by parsing html as a string to html like this {{ html: '<p>sample text</p>'}} ? Check this, it works for me https://snack.expo.io/B1jv50gyH